# From rstudio to database

Tags: r, sql-server, database, rstudio

I want to load the data into the database from the user's input. When user enter the ID and Name and click the upload button it need to be store in the MS Sql server. The code get executing and but the value is not storing.

```
library(shiny)
library(odbc)
shinyApp(
ui<-fluidPage(
    textInput("ID", label = h3("Enter your studentID"), value = ""),
    hr(),
    fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value"))),
    textInput("Name", label = h3("Enter your name"), value = ""),
    hr(),
    fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value"))),
    actionButton("submit","upload")
),
server<-
    function(input,output) {
        observeEvent(input$submit,{
            con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "databaseName", uid = "userID", pwd = "$$$$$")
            dbSendQuery(con,"insert into tblname(ID,Name) values(input$ID,input$Name)")
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: `input$Name` is an R variable, and I doubt the API knows to replace this in the SQL string.  But first, can you verify that your database connection is working?

Comment: Like you mentioned, I am pretty sure that's not the correct value to be inserted in the query. My connection is good and my query alone is executing if I give some values for example "dbSendQuery(con,"insert into tblname(ID,Name) 
          values(123,'Superman')")

Comment: In order for me to help you, I need to know what is working and what isn't.  Are you certain that you can connect to SQL Server from your R script?

Comment: Just a guess but try replacing `"insert into tblname(ID,Name) values(input$ID,input$Name)"` with `paste("insert into", tblname(ID,Name), "values(" input$ID,input$Name,")")`

Comment: I am pretty sure, my connection is working good. I am concerned about what values should I give in the query part.